# Generate a CSV FIle foreach item and list it on this listview

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

*I'm workin on a wpf c#  solution and I want to write a CSV File for each item in my listview using LinqToCsv, the CSV will be populated by the fields from database. i didn't find a solution for this, now my code generate one csv file including all data and not data for each item.
here is my code and a screen of my listview if someone can help me!*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgpgq.jpg

```
private void Rechercher_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TOPSAGEEntities db = new TOPSAGEEntities();

        var query = from fournisseur in db.F_COMPTET
                    join email in db.F_ECHEANCES on fournisseur.CT_Intitule equals email.ECH_Intitule
                    //where email.cbModification.ToString().Contains(DatePicker.Text)
                    select new { fournisseur = email.ECH_Intitule, email = fournisseur.CT_EMail, date = email.cbModification};

        var infoEcheances = from i in db.F_ECHEANCES
                            select new {i.ECH_DateEch, i.CG_Num, i.ECH_Piece, i.ECH_RefPiece, i.ECH_Montant, i.ECH_Libelle};



        CsvFileDescription outpCsvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ',',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
        };

        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
        string myPath = @"C:\Users\DefaultAccount\Desktop\Projet Top Of Travel\FichiersCSV\";
        string finalPath = myPath + "test.csv";

        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(listView.Items);

        foreach (var list in myList)
        {
            cc.Write(infoEcheances, finalPath, outpCsvFileDescription);
        }

        //MessageBox.Show(DatePicker.SelectedDate.ToString());
        listView.DataContext = query.ToList().Distinct();
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a path like `"%userprofile%\Desktop\Projet Top Of Travel\FichiersCSV\"` where `%userprofile%` will be the parh to the user folder instead of DefaultAccount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `cc`, `myPath` and `finalPath` inside `foreach` loop

```
CsvFileDescription outpCsvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = ',',
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
};

ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(listView.Items);
int counter = 1;

foreach (var list in myList)
{
    CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
    string myPath = @"C:\Users\DefaultAccount\Desktop\Projet Top Of Travel\FichiersCSV\";
    string filename = string.Format("test{0}.csv", counter);
    string finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(myPath, filename);

    cc.Write(infoEcheances, finalPath, outpCsvFileDescription);

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: i got an error of Path which is an ambiguous reference between System.Windows.Shapes.Path and System.IO.Path

Comment: It's System.IO.Path (we're dealing with paths on filesystem, not drawing any shapes :)). I've edited answer.